# Slow Karma Unit Tests

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, webpack, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I wrote unit tests for a small reach application using Jasmine and Karma.And Karma is running slow for these tests.

This is my karma config:

```
var unitTestReportOutputDir = 'unit-test-report';

module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    reporters: ['dots'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: false,        
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    autoWatchBatchDelay: 300,
    exclude: ['./test/data/*.js'],
    files: [
        'tests.webpack.js'],

    preprocessors: {
        'tests.webpack.js': ['webpack']
    },
    webpack: require('./webpack.config.js'),

    webpackMiddleware: {
        noInfo: true
    },
    htmlReporter: {
        outputDir: unitTestReportOutputDir, // where to put the reports
        focusOnFailures: true, // reports show failures on start
        namedFiles: true, // name files instead of creating sub-directories
        pageTitle: 'Unit Test Report', // page title for reports; browser info by default
        urlFriendlyName: false, // simply replaces spaces with _ for files/dirs
        reportName: 'test-summary', // report summary filename; browser info by default
        // experimental
        preserveDescribeNesting: false, // folded suites stay folded
        foldAll: false, // reports start folded (only with preserveDescribeNesting)
    }
});
```

}

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglify-js-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

devtool: 'inline-source-map',
entry: ['./src/index.js'],
output: {path: path.resolve(__dirname, "builds"), filename: 'bundle.js'},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.sass$/,
            exclude: '/node_modules/',
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                loader: "css-loader!sass-loader"
            })
        }
    ]
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.sass']
},
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: "stylesheets/style.css",
        disable: false,
        allChunks: true
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        "$": "jquery",
        "jQuery": "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
        }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        }
    })
]
```

};

What do you guys usually do to speed up Karma in running unit tests ?

I put the code at: https://github.com/zainulfranciscus/karma-test
karma took 1 min 15 sec to start and 33 seconds to ran the tests, whenever I updated a test. There are 35 unit tests

Thank you.

Comment: How many tests are you running and how slow is slow?

Comment: you might want to have 2 webpack configs -- separate for production and testing (actually you'll have 3 including some common stuff for both) -- you don't really need to minify all files and generate source maps for each tests run

Comment: @xmike I will create 2 webpack configs and see if there are any improvements.

Comment: @Leon let me measure time required to run the test and get back to you. I will also share the source code from github soon. Thank you

Comment: @Leon there are 35 unit tests. It took karma 1 min 15 sec to start. And 33 seconds to ran the tests, whenever I updated a test

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `karma-parallel` plugin here: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-parallel

More popular and `karma-webpack` compatible compared to the `karma-sharding` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [karma-sharding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-sharding)? This plugin addresses some memory usage problems with some browsers, and numerous or memory intensive specs.

It will not run your tests all in parallel, but as of version 4.0.0, it supports parallel browser execution(i.e. will shard tests across browsers listed in your `karma.conf.js`)

Comment: Hi, I will install that plugin and see if it improve the execution time.

Comment: What was the result?